# Advanced french for business and customer service

Tags: ressources, commerce

I did French till high school and I can speak relatively well but with an accent and a lack of fluidity with words.

I will starting a new customer-facing role dealing with IT projects and I desperately need to improve my French from an intermediate level to an advanced level in the customer service, business domains.

Any advice or sites ? 
I am already practising to read French newspapers, listening to radio and mimicking, etc.

Comment: Change nothing : a little english accent is the must in french business domain.

Comment: @Istao agreed if it is indeed a *little* english accent ;-) A thick one would be less appreciated, even more so if dealing with customers rather than just technical coworkers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En France il existe ce qu'on appelle, selon les endroits, des *[Cafés Langues](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=&as_epq=caf%C3%A9%20langues&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=)* ou des *[Tandems linguistiques](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=tandem%20linguistiques&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=)* où on rencontre de façon conviviale et pour des discussions informelles des locuteurs dont on veut pratiquer la langue, un échange de services en quelque sorte. Tu peux te renseigner pour voir si ça existe dans ton pays/ta ville. Sinon si tu habites une assez grande ville ou pas loin d'une grande ville peut-être peux-tu démarrer le tien ?  Pour te donner des idées voici un exemple de [site français](http://tandem-linguistique.org/) (mais c'est pas le seul) qui permet de trouver des contacts (France uniquement).

Il y a aussi les échanges en tandems virtuels (par skype par exemple) : 
- [SharedTalk](http://www.sharedtalk.com/)
- [Totalingua](http://www.totalingua.com/)
- [Palabea](http://www.palabea.com/)
- [Polyglot Club](http://polyglotclub.com/)

Ce genre de conversations serait très utile pour le contact avec la clientèle, qui est ton but final.

Answer (score 1):

Il est possible que des cours de théâtre puissent vous permettre d'adapter vos connaissances actuelles à l'oralité liée à l'expression corporelle.

Un professeur corrigera immédiatement les erreurs de prononciations et d'accentuations, mais surtout vous permettra de manifester vos émotions au travers d'une langue offrant mille et une nuances pour l'expression des sentiments.

Et puis les cours collectifs ouvrent sur des rencontres riches de personnalités différentes que vous risquez de retrouver dans vos activités professionnelles.